# HttpWebRequest giving "The request timed out" in Mono

Tags: c#, ubuntu, mono, servicestack, threadpool

is there any Mono expert here?

When I'm make a request to another server it is throwing an execption with the error "The request timed out" and I can't make more requests to that site. I'm using ServiceStack v3 with SmarthThreadPool and I already have configured the MONO_THREADS_PER_CPU to 100 but keeps working for a while then this happens. I imagine that the threads are not being disposed correctly so there comes a time when I can't create more requests.

This is running on Ubuntu 14.04 with mono version 4.0.1, I also read that in the alpha version 4.2 they fixed a lot of bugs with the ThreadPool, but I haven't test it in production yet. Any advice or suggestion? I'm out of ideas of what to do know and I'm still having downtimes of the API because of this.

Many, many thanks in advance :)

Here is the code I'm using:

```
private static string GetRawJson(string requestUrl, string ipAddress) {
        ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 1000;
        ServicePointManager.UseNagleAlgorithm = false;
        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;

        var requestResponse = string.Empty;
        var request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(requestUrl);
        request.Proxy = null;
        request.KeepAlive = true;
        request.Timeout = 800;
        request.Headers.Add("X-Forwarded-For", ipAddress);

        using (var response = request.GetResponse()) {
            using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream()) {
                if (stream != null) {
                    using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream)) {
                        requestResponse = reader.ReadToEnd();
                        reader.Close();
                    }
                    stream.Close();
                }                        
            }
            response.Close();
        }

        return requestResponse;
    }
```

Comment: test Mono 4.2.x and let us know...

Comment: sure thing! I'll let you know

Comment: Same problem with Mono 4.2.1 http://stackoverflow.com/q/35101200/710955

Comment: We made the update a month ago and we haven't seen the error anymore, but we had to switch to HttpClient